# PHP bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm searching and searching but i didnt find the problem, hope you can help me:

> "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
>   number of parameters in prepared statement in "mydir" on line 24"

```
<?php
class Tunier {

    // name of Tunier
    protected $tunier_name;
    // count of participants
    protected $participant_count;

    function __construct($name, $participant) {
        // mysqli connection
        $db = new mysqli('localhost','root','','tuniere') or die ('Cant connect to MySql Please try later again');

        $this->tunier_name = $name or die('---');
        $this->participant = $participant or die('---');

        // einrichtung der Tabelle
        $query = 'CREATE TABLE `?`(
                                                    `?` VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
                                                    `?` INT(2) NOT NULL,
                                                    `id_spieler` INT(10) NULL                            
                                                    );';

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);        
        $stmt->bind_param('sss', $this->tunier_name, $this->tunier_name, $this->participant_count);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that you are misusing the prepared statements feature. Bind parameters are intended to inject data into your queries (numbers, literal strings...) not to inject operators, identifiers or keywords. There's no way to protect against SQL injection if you accept SQL commands from untrusted sources. In other words: **you cannot pass table or column names as bind parameters**.

The SQL parser does not just replace all `?` symbols blindly—it's a context sensitive tool. As a consequence, this:

```
`?`
```

... is not considered a placeholder but a literal identifier, thus the error.

E.g., in the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM `?`
WHERE foo=? OR bar='?' OR dot='How are you doing?'
```

... we have up to `?` symbols but the parser will only treat as placeholder the one at `foo=?` because, when code is parsed as SQL, that `?` is the only one that's located where literal values are expected. So:

1. The code will only run if you pass *one* parameter.
2. The query fill fail if you don't have a table called `?`.

Comment: i think i dont really unterstand your statement, im just inject data in my uery or not ?

Comment: @user2316478 I'll use different words: you cannot pass table or column names as bind parameters.

Comment: ah okay :), i thought i could like when im inserting data with the INSERT INTO statement

Answer (score 0):

No need `bind_param()` for your `table_name`

Change `Integer type` for `participant_count` in `bind_param()`

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssi', $this->tunier_name, $this->tunier_name, $this->participant_count);
```